# How to clear current commerce item in the shopping cart in ATG?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I tried to clear the current commerce item in ATG. I am getting clearing `commerceItems` in the cart but when I click  it twice the "clear cart button" its clearing. I don't know how to rectify this. I have tried the following:

```
 <dsp:input bean="ShoppingCart.deleteAll" value="clearcart" type="submit"/>
```

I used this bean only but it only works after clicking the clear button twice.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `handleDeleteAll` method in the FormHandler? Did you customise this? If you load the shopping cart, do you make any changes before you click 'clearcart'? Maybe, as a test, refresh the page and check if it works on the first click.

Comment: Your questions really don't give enough information for people to be able to help you which is why you don't seem to get many answers. Perhaps refer to the [article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) about working examples for how to ask better questions.

Comment: @radimpe why should i customize this handle method i have out of box method to delete all items in the shopping cart..

Comment: so i used that method but i am getting clearing when i click two time the clear button..